# Find if a line segment is a sub segment of another line

Tags: c

How do I find if a certain line is a sub segment of another line?

Line 1: (2,2) and (20,20)

Line 2: (5,5) and (15,15)

I know how to do this mathematically but having a hard time coding it in c. I found out that the slopes are equal but cant find a way to check that the lines are part of the same line and not just parallel.

Comment: you need to find both the slope and the intercept. Then see if the coordinates overlap there. Or alternatively you can see if you can reach the same point with the slope starting from one point ...

Comment: Remember that the lines, if parallel, might be horizontal, vertical, or slanted. You’ll probably have to handle a special case no matter what you do.

Comment: How would you do this mathematically?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I would just find equation of one line and plug in the co ordinates of the other to check if they match.
So according to you I can just check if two of the lines have the same slope and y intercept. but how do I check if one is a sub segment and simply not overlapping?

Comment: Needs you to apply the maths you already know https://ideone.com/xxfI0s

Comment: @TomZych the easy way to check for same slope is by cross-multiplying. Suppose one is `dx/dy` and the other is `du/dv`. If the slopes are the same then `dx*dv == du*dy`. This avoids special cases (except the zero length line).

Comment: Comparing the two slopes using == will rarely work, due to truncation and roundoff errors. You need to compare the absolute value of the difference of the slopes to a number that is small enough to be considered zero.

Comment: If you want to check whether line B is a sub segment of line A add two more sides C and D to form a quadrilateral. Ask yourself what the length of B+C+D would be if B was a sub segment of A.

Comment: @FredK with the method I stated, there is no division involved, and with integer arithmetic the results are exact. It avoids calculating the slopes at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane: With integer arithmetic the results are exact unless overflow occurs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil one would use a larger type.

Comment: @Weather Vane True, when only integers are involved.  But what if the user wants to know if the segment (6.1, 6.1) to (12.1, 12.1) is co-linear with the original line, or some other arbitrary line?

Comment: @FredK it's still no worse than calculating the slope, because there are no special cases such as a horizontal line. A great deal of this type of geometry is done by using [cross-products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be homework, so I will only sketch an answer. You will have to code it yourself.

First, are the slopes the same? If not, they only have one point in common; stop. Assuming the coordinates are integers, you can avoid floating-point errors by computing each *dx* and *dy*, and cross-multiplying (h/t to Weather Vane’s comment above).

Second, do the extended lines have a point in common? Can do this by finding y-intercepts or various other ways. If not, they’re parallel; stop.

Having reached this point, we know the segments are on the same line, so now we have to test the intervals. If they’re horizontal, look at *x*; if vertical, look at *y*; if slanted, pick one coordinate, either one will work.

Sort each pair of endpoints to get *a* and *b* such that *a* < *b*. Then, simply compare the leftmost endpoints of each segment, and the rightmost. Remember that either or both might be equal.